# Unable to display uploaded images via PHP into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, jpeg

I've trimmed my code down to the bare minimum to try to find why I cannot display any image that I upload & store via PHP into MySQL. If anyone can point out my error(s) I'd be most grateful.

On execution, the browser reports that the image cannot be displayed as it contains errors.

However, the image uploads & displays fine in other databases running in this same environment.

I've checked that the database holds a blob after upload.

I guess I'm missing something obvious.

Upload form..

```
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="imagetestprocess.php" method="post">
<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Form handler..

```
<?php
include("../mylibrary/login.php");

login();

$imagefile = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$imagefile = mysql_real_escape_string($imagefile);
$query="UPDATE pieces SET image_full='$imagefile' WHERE assetno='1'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

?>
```

Image displayer..

```
<?php
include("../mylibrary/login.php");

login();
echo "<body>";
echo "before";
echo "<img src=\"showimage.php\" alt=\"showimage\">";
echo "after";

?>
```

called function...

```
<?php
include("../mylibrary/login.php");
login();
$query = "select * from pieces where assetno='1'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$image=$row['image_full'];
header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
echo $image;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

change the image_full field type to `MEDIUMBLOB / BLOB`

user this `$image = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents("image.jpg")));`
instead of `$imagefile = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);`

and in show image function use image as below.

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
echo base64_decode($image);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  The image_full field is already a mediumblob.

Did you mean.. $imagefile = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])));

It made no difference I'm afraid.

Comment: midiumblob is good. and the encode will encode your file_get_content so you will not have issue of garbage character.chunk_split will split a string into smaller chunks so it good to read the image content when it is large string.

Answer (score 0):

use mysql_escape_string or addslashes and clear your browser cache to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions does not work for you.
Try increasing the length of the field in database.
if still it does not work,
You can check if the image format is RGB or CMYK.
format shoud be RGB to see on screen.
To make it sure you can try opening the same image file in browser.

Comment: Yes, I can open the source file in Firefox, no problem. The image is around 50K & I'm storing it in a mediumblob

Comment: Ok,
Chek for 

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
 echo "some error in file upload";  
}

but i think its not good practice to save images in database.
better will be to save the image in server using move_uploaded_file() and save the image path only in database.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with your database encoding. some encoding does not support binary data.

If you cannot change the encoding, maybe you css base64 encode the data before saving and decode it when displaying. only thing is base64 will increase the size by 3.